# Need to arrange af:selectManyCheckbox in three columns

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a list of items (16 in number) for which I need to provide Check boxes.
I've used af:selectManyCheckbox to render them. The challenge is to render these 16 items in 3 columns. Tried by placing the af:selectManyCheckbox in h:panelGrid with "columns=3" but it didn't work. I'm just able to get the list in one single column.

```
<h:panelGrid cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" columns="2"
                 id="pg2" width="100%">
        <af:selectManyCheckbox id="smc1" label="Languages">
            <af:forEach items="#{pageFlowScope.listingCreateBean.languageList}"
                        var="language">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{language.value}"
                              itemLabel="#{language.label}" id="si1"/>
            </af:forEach>
        </af:selectManyCheckbox>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: I dont think you can do this with selectManyCheckbox . If you can explain ur use case , probably there is some other way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `<af:panelFormLayout>` component and set the columns to `3` and rows to `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Throw away **af:selectManyCheckbox**.
Only one sure way to achive your goal is to use **af:iterator** or **af:forEach** with **af:selectBooleanCheckbox** and any layout components combination to get desired layout.

And avoid using non-adf components (like h:panelGrid), it can cause a lot of trouble with pprs and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
.checkbox-grid {
    width: 100%;
}

.checkbox-grid .x2f{
    width: 100%;
}

.checkbox-grid div {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    /* 25% 4columns, 33% 3columns, 50% 2columns */
    width: 25%; 
} 
</style>


<af:selectManyCheckbox  value="#{listaFormatos}" styleClass="checkbox-grid">
   <af:forEach var="item" items="#{posiblesListaFormatos}" >
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{item.value}" itemValue="#{item.value}" id="si2"/>
   </af:forEach>
</af:selectManyCheckbox>
```